# Linear regression of higher order polynomial with slope constraint

Tags: regression, polynomial, constrained-regression, constraint

I am trying to constrain the coefficients on a higher order polynomial (let's say an order 6) for the curve to be decreasing.

I have found this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220614/linear-regression-polynomial-slope-constraint-in-r), where the fitting of a 3rd order polynomial is being fit, but that will not fit my data unfortunately.

Am I right in assuming that it is technically impossible to constraint a higher order polynomial?
This would mean:

[image: f(.)= ax^{6} + bx^{5} + cx^{4} + dx^{3} + ex^{2} + f]

Which means:

[image]

Which is not possible to solve?

What can I do then to force a constraint on the shape of a higher order polynomial?

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?