Can IRLS deal with inequallity constrains? What should I use otherwise?
I have a set of observed data points $p_i = (a_i,b_i)$, and a common constant $c$. Theoretically, the points are supposed to follow the equation:
$$a_i = b_i + x_1 + x_2(b_i + c)$$
I aim to find the optimal $(x_1, x_2)$ that minimizes the error. The values of $(x_1, x_2)$ are subject to the following constraints:
$$ -w \leq x_1 \leq w$$
$$-1 \leq x_2 \leq w - 1$$
I have tried formulating the following problem:
$$\min_x f(x) = \Sigma_i^{N-1} (a_i - b_i - x_1 - x_2(b_i + c))^2$$
Or
$$\min_x f(x) = \left\|\overrightarrow{\alpha} - x_1 - x_2\overrightarrow{\beta}\right\|_2^2$$
$$S.T. -w \leq x_1 \leq w$$
$$-1 \leq x_2 \leq w - 1$$
The original solution I was handed, utilized iterated reweighted least-square (IRLS), ignoring the constraints. However, this gives us non-feasible solutions.
Can the IRLS algorithm be adapted to have inequality constraints? Otherwise, what is the best optimizer or regression for this problem?

(1) It depends on what "optimal" means.  How do you measure it? (2) Why are you applying the square root, which is superfluous for optimization? Likewise, why haven't you algebraically simplified this expression, which has the form $|\alpha - x_1 + \beta x_2|$? These both suggest the presence of typographical errors. (3) Your formulation makes no sense for any $N\gt 1:$ presumably you are doing something like summing or averaging over your data.  Could you give a complete, accurate description of this problem?

Saying much the same as part of whuber's comment -- but in slightly different words: Please edit so that the thing you're asking about optimizing contains the $n$ points you mention, not just a single one. It's not obvious how the loss function (thing being optimized) relates to the actual situation with $n$ data points.

@whuber thanks for your comment. I tried editing to create a clearer question.

Are you familiar with constrained optimization? Things like Lagrange multipliers, etc.

@Firebug, a bit. I tried applying Karush-Kuhn-Tucker to no avail. See my question here.

This is known as constrained regression: follow the link to see a list of our posts that refer to it.  There's a thorough, general account at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220614, for instance.

Not sure if you want to work out the solution manually. If not, you could use the L-BFGS-B algorithm that is implemented standard statistical programming packages (e.g., in optim() in R, scipy.optimize.minimize() in Python).

@Thom I need to implement this in cpp from scratch.
